# seaborn cannot find PathCollection containing the data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

From the [seaborn tutorial](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) I have plotted a plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.swarmplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
```

And now I would like to have the handle to the PathCollection containing the data to [make in interactive using mpld3](https://mpld3.github.io/examples/scatter_tooltip.html). I look at the output `ax` children and I get the following list:

```
[<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7828d325f8>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x782824a518>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x782824ab38>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x782824a748>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x782824a940>,
 <matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x782824acf8>,
 <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x78282e5518>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x78282fb710>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x78282fb0b8>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x78282fb208>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x78282fb0f0>]
```

However when I look for data in the PathCollection it is empty
`ax.get_children()[0].get_array()`

How can I find a handle to the PathCollection containing the data points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PathCollection` containing the data points is `ax.get_children()[0]`. The result of calling `.get_array()` is `None` (not empty) but that won't prevent you from usimg mplot3d with the `PathCollection`. This code works for me:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.swarmplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(ax.get_children()[0],
                                          labels=tips.total_bill.tolist())
mpld3.plugins.connect(plt.gcf(), tooltip)
mpld3.show()
```

Made a [Jupiter notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/595fd4f293fecc1cdde62c58fae49163) just for the fun.

Comment: I don''t know, it does not seem to be relevant to you purpose so I did not look much into it.

Comment: @HananShteingart What's your actual issue? What do you want `.get_array()` for? You don't need it to plot the swarmplot with `mplotd3` and the `tooltip` plugin.

Comment: Thanks @Goyo for your help, I just tried to understand what's going on under the hood

Comment: This does not work properly as the labels are not in the same order as the rows in the dataframe. Check yourself by plotting the figure and checking the labels.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and cannot retrieve the row index corresponding to each point (which would allow to annotate each point in the plot in the right order). A solution specific to the example above howerver would be to replace the labels argument to `labels=ax.get_children()[0].get_offsets()[:, 0])`